# Вопрос о фреймворках

Tags: framework, java

Всем доброго времени суток.
Гугл по запросу "фреймворк для приложения" выдает кучу страниц, на которых встречается "ВЕБ-фреймворк для приложения".
Возник следующий вопрос: а бывают ли НЕ веб-фреймворки? И если оные в природе существуют, то не могли бы вы мне подсказать парочку таких для Java.
Спасибо.

Comment: Начните со значения слова framework и вы поймете, что бывают не web-фреймворки. Далее все просто. У вас есть задача - например распределенные вычисления. Значит вам нужен фреймворк для распределенных вычислений. Идете в гугл/яндекс и получаете ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: «Фреймворк» — достаточно общее понятие. Ответ зависит от того, что вы имеете в виду. Например, Swing — графический фреймворк.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за ответы. буду гуглить.

Answer (score 2):

Парочка примеров:

- [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) - фреймворк общего назначения, состоящий из кучи модулей для решения различных задач.
- [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) - MVC-фреймворк для построения Swing-приложений.
- [Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/) - OSGi фреймворк.